# npm ERR! Failed during build script on github actions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, npm, github-actions

I have frontend app written in react. I need to deploy it on azure. Moreover i have to use github actions. During building i get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react_with_mobix@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react_with_mobix@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-06-25T18_19_29_860Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

My .yml file looks:

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - uj-ebiznes-front

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Node.js version
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '14.x'

    - name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        CI=false npm install
        CI=false npm run build --if-present
    
    - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'app_name'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: //there's my secret
        package: .
```

I have already changed line with run on:

```
run: |
        CI=false npm install
        CI=false npm run build --if-present
```

I found some questions on github issues and on stackOverflow where answers indicate on this line. But it didn't help me.

Please, could you help me? Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

**`For npm error`:-**

Try with Create a new file inside your(VS) project with `.env`
Then inside the `.env` file write this following code and save it.

> `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true

The above command will help you in resolving the `npm error.`
After successfully create then try to start the npm and check. This can be work for your issue.

Or, For more information about  **configuring your node.js app to azure web app** Refer this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux).

Deploy the **node.js app to App Service from  your local Git** repository to Azure. Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/tutorial-vscode-azure-cli-node/tutorial-vscode-azure-cli-node-04).

Comment: If above mentioned answer helped you , could you please accept the answer as solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future .

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error while deploying my react app on azure static web app service.

The error occurs because your code may be having warnings that will fail your build. In your .yml file, add an env setting, and inside that, make CI: false like this:

```
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    env:
      CI: false
    steps:
```